# Как на WordPress сделать pdf фаил только для просмотра?

Tags: wordpress

Как можно на WordPress защитить фаил от скачивания и принта и сделать его только для просмотра?

Answer (score 0):

Я на своих клиентских проектах использую сервис [infoprotector](http://infoprotector.ru), который защищает от копирования и pdf и doc и video. Товарищи пиарят плагин под WordPress под названием [CopySafe PDF Protection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-copysafe-pdf/). Попробуйте, может и вам подойжет.

Answer (score 0):

Максимум, что вы можете сделать, это **усложнить** получение документа с помощью какой-нибудь **DRM**. Но DRM работает только тогда, когда просмотрщик с ней совместим, а значит, от произвольного пользователя это не спасёт. Только если вы планируете показывать документ с машин, которым вы доверяете, и на которых нет средств, чтобы его скачать или напечатать.

Вот [одно из бурных обсуждений о добавлении DRM-подобных фич в `pdf.js`](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=792816). Как видно, они ещё **не** добавлены.

Так что для широкой аудитории — **никак**.